# Is there any text editor which supports Markdown (Ask Ubuntu's formatting style)?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, markdown

Is there any text editor with support for [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) ([formatting syntax used by Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)) which can be used to write questions or answers while you are offline?

Comment: The overkill option, as always, is emacs. `markdown-mode` works well, but I wouldn't be surprised if someone had built an entire asynchronous Stack Exchange client in emacs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [Retext](http://packages.ubuntu.com/retext) which supports markdown. Retext has been in Ubuntu since 12.04 precise. For earlier Ubuntu releases, or if you want a more recent version of Retext, get it from [the project home page](http://sourceforge.net/p/retext/home/ReText/) or from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emitya57/+archive/ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mitya57/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install retext
```

This will install Retext.

#### If you want a gedit plugin with markdown support:

1. [Download this](https://github.com/jpfleury/gedit-markdown) and extract the file in `~/Download` directory.
2. Open a terminal, `cd` to the `~/Downloads/gedit-markdown-master` directory  and run `./gedit-markdown.sh install`.
3. Restart Gedit and you have a markdown plugin, enable it and enjoy ! .

#### Note: You can anytime preview markdown by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: I don't know of such. You can also use your favorite text editor with some command line markup tool (i.e. [python markdown](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Command_Line)) or have a look at this: [Markdown for the Gedit](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2011/06/markdown-for-the-gedit-text-editor-on-ubuntu-11-04/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have edited the answer to include more things and I think, I can accept this.

Comment: @zetah. The Gedit download url is 404.

Comment: @Parto, try here: http://www.jpfleury.net/en/software/gedit-markdown.php (did not test it, just found by Google)

Answer (score 11):

You can try [Retext](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/retext/) or [Haroopad](http://pad.haroopress.com/) (both let you edit your markdown code and preview it)

### Retext

[image]

[Image source](http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/10/12/markdown-editor-for-ubuntu-12-0412-10/)

### Haroopad

[image]

[Image Source - Haroopad](http://pad.haroopress.com)

Comment: Is haroopad built on electron like atom?

Comment: @Anwar nwjs I think

Answer (score 6):

## Remarkable

[image: Remarkable Main Screenshot]

[Remarkable](https://remarkableapp.github.io) is a fully featured [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) editor with the following features:

- Live Preview
- Syntax Highlighting
- Support for [GitHub flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/)
- Editor specialized exclusively for Markdown
- Custom CSS
- Export to HTML & PDF
- [And More...](https://remarkableapp.github.io/linux.html)

[image: Remarkable with Dark GTK3 Theme]

Homepage: [Remarkable App](https://remarkableapp.github.io)
Source Repo: [Remarkable on GitHub](https://github.com/jamiemcg/Remarkable)
License: Open Source under [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
Download: [Remarkable's Download page](https://remarkableapp.github.io/linux/download.html) provides *deb* package for Ubuntu

Comment: Wow! That's a nice application. +1. but already accepted the answer

Answer (score 5):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) has built-in support for Markdown editing;

You can hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> at any time to toggle the Markdown preview window:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh! That's nice