# What markdown readers are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, markdown

First of all, everything I find seems to be an editor. I don't want an editor. I want a reader. I want a window that shows me the rendered markdown file, not its source. Sure, I don't care if it also edits, but if I cannot set it up to display just the rendered markdown on startup then it's not what I'm looking for.

Second, the few actual readers out there are browser based. I don't want to open the browser to read a rendered markdown file. I want a standalone window that does just that.

Lastly, I want the rendered markdown file to follow my GTK/QT theme, or at least have settings to do it.

I would prefer it to not be Electron-based.

The closest thing I've got to it is the terminal program Glow, but because it's a terminal program, it has some obvious limitations in its capability of rendering a markdown file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any text editor which supports Markdown (Ask Ubuntu's formatting style)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136331/is-there-any-text-editor-which-supports-markdown-ask-ubuntus-formatting-style)

Comment: They all require a key combo to enter preview mode, it's not what opens by default. Also, non of them really gives a damn about my theme in the preview, also, some of them only render the preview side by side with the source and not it exclusively.

I could live with one of them, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'd rather stick to Glow.

Comment: Typora is the best markdown editor in the Ubuntu repositories. It grabs everything off the webpage and it works great. I don't care what anyone says about keyboard combinations and theming.

Comment: Read the title again: I'm looking for a reader, not an editor.

Comment: Eh, just make a html using pandoc and open it using any browser

Comment: Please don't accuse me of being unable to read. It's rude and offensive.

Comment: Janking something up with Pandoc is exactly what I was trying to avoid. Karel, nobody accused you to not be able to read, but if I ask for a reader and you reply: "Typora is the best markdown editor", I find hard to think we are on the same page.

Comment: I don't believe there is an application that *only reads* markdown. You said in your original post that you didn't care if it was also an editor, so I don't understand the hostility at suggesting Typora. Typora is a markdown editor, but it is a very clean and minimal WYSIWYG editor. When you open a markdown file in Typora, it is rendered markdown. Typora also has themes. However typora is also not free software, so that is a downside. Please respect the [code of conduct](https://askubuntu.com/conduct) if you wish to interact with the Ubuntu community in the future.

Comment: If it's proprietary software then I won't use it for ethical reasons. (Also, it's also true that the person has not done the best to introduce it in a way that looks relevant to my question, but I should have researched it a bit more, that's on me)

Comment: I have found one that sorta works: MarkText. It's a Electron app, which is kind of a let down (and it also means it doesn't automatically pick up on my theme), and does not support custom themes as of now, but at least that feature is planned.

Answer (score 1):

[Formiko](https://github.com/ondratu/formiko) is a Gtk3 markdown editor written in Python. It does have a preview only mode and it will remember to enter that mode on startup once it's selected the first time, but the preview is currently unstable.

[Marktext](https://github.com/marktext/marktext/) is an Electron WYSIWYG markdown editor (the preview mode is also the edit mode, everything except the section that is currently being edited will be rendered). It does not currently support custom themes, but the feature is planned to eventually arrive.

Comment: This seems to ignore the actual question asked: "I don't want an editor. I want a reader."